# What happens if a character snorts Dust of Sneezing and Choking?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

According to [the item description](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Dust%20of%20Sneezing%20and%20Choking):

> When you use an action to throw a handful of the dust into the air, you and each creature that needs to breathe within 30 feet of you must succeed on a DC 15 Constitution saving throw or become unable to breathe while sneezing uncontrollably.

If a character (who needs to breathe) snorts the dust, they're not throwing it into the air, so the rules do not specify what happens in this case. See [What happens if a character snorts Dust of Disappearance?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/162829/what-happens-if-a-character-snorts-dust-of-disappearance)

As DM, I know how I would rule this (the character would have to make a save), but I am interested in the RAW interpretation. If I'm playing in an organized play context, can I tell my DM that no, according to the book, my character that snorted this dust won't suffer anything worse than if they'd snorted mundane dust (not that I'd ever waste a magic item in such a dumb way)?

Answer (score 8):

### You would suffer the effects of having snorted dust

You would probably end up sneezing and choking due to inhaling dust, but it would not be a magical sneezing and choking. The description states:

> When you use an action to throw a handful of the dust into the air[...]

You have not taken that action and therefore do not get the effects of the magic dust.

Having inhaled dust (accidentally) before, I'm not entirely sure what the difference between *Dust of Sneezing and Choking* and Just Dust is.

Comment: For what it's worth, fully revoking the ability to breathe as a game mechanic is very different (as it can result in death in a matter of seconds) than the effect of inhaling dust in the real world.

Comment: @DavidCoffron That line is there for comedy, but I did actually forgot the full effect of the dust, didn't realize it rendered you incapacitated. Although I believe it's unlikely to cause death, as you have 5 rounds before you start the dying process and that's only if you have a negative con mod.

Comment: You don't get 5 rounds. [You get a number of rounds equal to your Constitution modifier](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Suffocating) to start dying and then have to make Death Saving Throws. Even if you save against the dust while dying, you are still at 0 hit points then and have to be stabilized (and before you succeed on the dust ST, you can't be stabilized).

Comment: @DavidCoffron Ahh, I see my mistake. I included the time it would take to run out of air, which is bypassed since the dust specifically says you are suffocating

Comment: It only really matters on low Constitution creatures. Here's the numbers: [How deadly is Dust of Sneezing and Choking?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/162879/41726)